# @sce.trustAsHtml and 'TM' symbol lock up mobile browser

Tags: angularjs

Has anyone else seen anything like this?  Could I be misunderstanding the problem?

I have an angular application which involves "injecting" html pulled into the app via ajax.  I will code of how I'm doing that below.

What I've found is that if I have a "TM" symbol (ascii 8482) in the html I inject, it will lock up the browser completely, but only on mobile browsers. Tried it on desktop chrome / FF / IE and it's fine.  But on mobile Chrome / Dolphin / Safari / (didnt try mobile FF) , it locks up the browser.

I hardly believe it myself, but soon as I took the "TM" symbol out of the html, everything is fine.

I use code like this - where "data" = the html i retrieve via ajax:

```
                var injector = $('#ngCourseDrilldown').injector();
                var $compile = injector.get('$compile');

                // Compile the HTML into a linking function...
                var linkFn = $compile(data);

                // HEre's another way to get the scope for the controller
                var theScope = $('#mainController').scope();

                var elem = linkFn($scope);  

                $('#ajaxTarget').append(elem);

                // Now that the content has been compiled, linked,
                // and added to the DOM, we must trigger a digest cycle
                // on the scope we used in order to update bindings.
                $scope.$digest();
```